# Dynamic vector/list creation

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I'd like to dynamic build a vector/list.

I've built this function `generate-map` that return a `map`, like:

```
{:key 1, :value 1, :other [...]}
```

In this other function `get-statement`, I have a `doseq` calling this `generate-map` function.

```
(defn get-statement
  [st] 
  (doseq [s st] (generate-map s)))
```

I'd like to build one map joining all these `generate-maps` returns over the `doseq` call, e.g.:

```
[{:key 1, :value 1, :other [...]}
 {:key 2, :value 2, :other [...]}
 {:key 3, :value 3, :other [...]}]
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Don't use `doseq` since you need the result. Use `for`. 2. Look up the `into` function. `(into {}...)`. I'd post an answer, but I'm on the clock :/

Comment: 3. The result you want to create looks illegal; a map needs to be key/value pairs. Did you mean you want a vector of maps?

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Comment: Np. Check the answer I just posted. It elaborates on the topics a bit.

Comment: Note, I updated the answer right before you accepted it, so I'm not sure if you saw the edit. There's a much shorter version than using `for`. Evidently I'm tired. Not sure why my mind jumped immediately to `(into [] (for ...))`. `mapv` is almost definitely the right tool for the job here, unless you need some kind of filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create some maps, and put them into a vector, just use a `for`, mixed with either `vec` or `(into [] ...)`:

```
(into [] ; ... and place them in a vector
  (for [d data] ; ...for each datum in data...
    (generate-map d))) ; Generate a map...
```

Or `mapv`:

```
(mapv generate-map data) ; Super succinct!
```

Never use `doseq` for something like this. `doseq` doesn't return anything, so you'd have to use some `atom` or other effect mess to actually get anything out of the loop.

- Use `doseq` when you need to execute a side effect, and don't directly need any results from it.
- Use `for`, `map`, `reduce` (or any other functional looping construct) if you need a result after looping.